# Installing execSync using Puppet

Tags: node.js, puppet, system-administration

I am writing a Puppet module to setup an application on our test servers. The testing environment requires us to install a node package called execSync (https://github.com/mgutz/execSync). Since execSync is a native package, it gets compiled on installation. When I try to manually install it on the server, it gets installed. However, when I do the same thing using Puppet, compilation step fails.

I have tried installing execSync using the puppetlabs-nodejs module (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-nodejs) and using `exec` defined type with command `npm install execSync` as well, and nothing seems to work. I have also checked that the right versions of nodejs and npm are used.

I would love to automate this process completely but nothing seems to work and I have run out of options. What could be the possible reasons?

**Edited:**

Here is the manifest I am using:

```
exec { 'npm-install':
        command => 'npm install execSync',
        cwd => '/var/www/appv3',
        path => '/usr/local/node/node-default/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
        logoutput => true,
}
```

I run this using `puppet apply`.

This is what I see in the console output:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for test.app.com in environment production in 0.54 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/execSync
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/execSync
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/temp
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/temp
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: 
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: > execSync@1.0.2 install /var/www/appv3frontend_testapp.vwo.com/node_modules/execSync
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: > node install.js
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: 
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: [execsync v1.0.2] Attempting to compile native extensions.
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: [execSync v1.0.2]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns:     Native code compile failed!!
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: execSync@1.0.2 node_modules/execSync
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: └── temp@0.5.1 (rimraf@2.1.4)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[npm-install]/returns: executed successfully
```

The same thing works just fine when I run the command manually. The compilation happens successfully.

Comment: From the information you provided, it could be literally anything. Please provide debug logs etc.

Comment: When you say that it works when you run it manually, are you using the same user and environment as puppet?

Comment: @ChrisPitman Yes. Running `puppet apply` as root. `path` variable has been set to the same as I have when I try to install manually.

Comment: @FelixFrank Just edited the question and added more information. Anything else you think that might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I had been trying to understand what was different in the two. It seems that the environment was different. The compilation step requires the `HOME` env variable to be set. When it is not set, the compilation step fails without any helpful error messages.

Finally, ended up using the following manifest:

```
exec { 'npm-install':
        command => 'npm install execSync',
        cwd => '/var/www/appv3',
        path => '/usr/local/node/node-default/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
        environment => ['HOME=/root'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use fully qualified paths when doing an exec, something like:

```
exec {'install-execSync':
  command  => '/usr/local/bin/npm install execSync',
}
```

For automating the process completely with the puppetlabs module (which you want to do) we need more info.

Comment: Well as I said, I am already all that you have mentioned in your answer.