# Puppet: Set env variables & boot app - variables undefined

Tags: linux, environment-variables, vagrant, puppet

I am using Puppet to provision my Vagrant box. Among a few other tasks, the `main.pp` file is creating the `/etc/environments` file, then daemonizing the node.js app I'm running. The node app requires a few environment variables, but they're returning undefined.

The relevant `main.pp` snippets:

```
class environment {
  file { "/etc/environment":
    ensure => present,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/environment/dev.env'
  }
}

class application {
  exec { "Daemonize API" :
    cwd => "/vagrant/api",
    command => "npm run watch",
    onlyif => ["test -d /vagrant/api/node_modules"],
    path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin"],
    require => Package['nodejs']
  }
}
```

One variable in particular that the environment class sets is `NODE_ENV` to development.

If I `vagrant ssh` and `echo $NODE_ENV`, `development` is returned, but the application `console.logs` `undefined`.

If I kill the daemon and reboot the app, everything is kosher again.

How can I get it so that, on provision, the environment variables are correctly set, and when the app is daemonized, it has access to them at the time of booting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell that runs your `exec` appears not to honor `/etc/environment`.

There is two ways to go about this.

#### Use the envrironment explicitly

Write a wrapper script that does a

```
. /etc/environment
```

before invoking the `npm` proper.

#### Set the needed variables via manifest

Pass the `environment` parameter to the `exec` like so:

```
exec { 'Daemonize API':
    environment => [ 'NODE_ENV=development, ],
    ...
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896943/3356612) might be related.